# How do I make Git remember I removed a plugin in Grails?

Tags: git, grails

I was working on a project and uninstalled facebook-connect plugin and added facebook-graph plugin. If I do another commit to capture this change what do I need to do?
I did a

```
git add .
```

and

```
git commmit -m 'swapped facebook-connect for facebook-graph'
```

Is there anything else I need to do to capture the change in source control?
I'm sure files were removed by the uninstall - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change in your source (and the only change that should be captured in source control) is in *application.properties* or *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*, depending on how you install the plugin.

The plugin is installed to *~/.grails/[grails-version]/projects/[project-name]/plugins/*, i.e. not under your grails projects source and thus not under source control.

Note that some plugins can create additional files under your source during install, like e.g. the grails-melody plugin that creates the config file *grails-app/conf/GrailsMelodyConfig.groovy*. If you compare *git status* before and after you install a plugin, you will quickly see which files are added.

Comment: oh ... guess my skills in git are really lacking. How would I figure out what has changed? I am using github if that helps.

Comment: You can use the command 'git status'. Modified files under version control will show up under "Changes not staged for commit" and newly created files, not under version control will show up under "Untracked files".

Comment: This will show you which files has changed / been added. If you want to see what has changed, use 'git diff'. Or if you use an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or STS/Eclipse you can see the changes in a nice gui.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure you need to keep the plugin code in your git repo.  There might be some advantages, but it also makes life a lot more difficult, as you are seeing.  You have to weigh if it is even worth it.

I personally don't check plugin code in.  I check in application.properties, which Grails can use to get the plugins it needs.  This works since you specify the plugin versions explicitly.

This means that for new developers, the first time they run the app Grails fetches the plugins for them.

Comment: Where would the plugin code get checked in from? I guess I'm referring more to files that plugins add to the app directory (grails-app or web-app). How would I know if I checked in plugin code?

Comment: Based off rlovtang's answer I did not check in /.grails/[grails-version]/projects/[project-name]/plugins/ if that is what you meant

Comment: "This means that for new developers, the first time they run the app Grails fetches the plugins for them" +1 Thanks. Good tip.

Answer (score 1):

On the git level alone, if you want to add all changes in the working folder, you need to

```
git add -A
```

This will track whether you added, deleted or modified files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a good way to compare a local copy to a remote copy? Guess I should check now to see if I missed anything +1